# Отмена старой грамматики

Tags: общие-вопросы

Мне попалась информация о том, что, согласно декрета совнаркома от 10 октября 1918 года касательно введения новой грамматики, и старая, и новая формы орфографии равноценны и равноправны. И, самое интересное, что, якобы, декрет действует по сей день. То есть, мы можем писать с ятями, и это не будет ошибкой. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Шухов:] "Неужто и солнце ихним декретам подчиняется?" ("Один день Ивана Денисовича").*

Полагаю, что вы или автор "информации" не совсем верно поняли суть.
Во-первых, не "новой грамматики", а только орфографии. Грамматику даже большевики ввести не в состоянии. Грамматика ихним декретам не подчиняется.
Во-вторых, речь там (по памяти) шла о том, что в течение десяти, кажется, лет новые правила могут применяться наравне со старыми при осуществлении контроля знаний учащихся, конкретный срок был оговорен в каком-то другом документе, что-то типа, говоря современным языком, "постановления о порядке введения в действие". В этой части никакой "отмены", понятно, не требуется за истечением срока действия. Фактически же уже менее чем через год новые правила почти повсеместно вытеснили старые даже в школе при всеобщей поддержке "снизу".

Во всех остальных случаях, в том числе и для преподавания, новая орфография вступала в силу немедленно с момента опубликования декрета. Естественно, что и тут Декрет никто не отменял.
Сам Декрет здесь: [ДЕКРЕТ О ВВЕДЕНИИ HOBOЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ | stcreserv.narod.ru](http://stcreserv.narod.ru/Tutorial/decret18.html)

И её одна реплика. Реформа эта проведена большевиками, но готовилась совсем не ими. Тщательная подготовка велась созданной Императорским указом Орфографической Комиссией, куда входили лучшие представители российской филологической школы (Шахматов, Фортунатов, Бодуэн де Куртене и др.), начиная с 1904. Она должна была состояться в 1914 г., но этим планам помешала война.
Тем не менее, ещё в марте 1917 г. одним из первых декретов Временного правительства кн. Львова была предпринята первая попытка упорядочить орфографию в соответствии с предложениями Комиссии. Тогда в частности учашимся было разрешено использовать оба варианта орфографии - именно этот пункт (в своей редакции) и включила новая власть в приснопамятный Декрет от 10.10.1918 г.

Comment: > Реформа это проведена большевиками, но
> готовилась совсем не ими.

Да, идея эта появилась ещё до революции. Ещё у Чехова можно прочитать в "Даме с собачкой"
(в цитате речь идёт о жене главного героя, которая себя считала **прогрессивной** женщиной).

> *Это была женщина  высокая, с темными бровями, прямая, важная, солидная и,
> как она сама  себя  называла,
> мыслящая. Она много читала, **не  писала
> в  письмах  "ъ"**,  называла  мужа  не
> Дмитрием, а Димитрием, а он втайне
> считал ее  недалекой,  узкой, 
> неизящной, боялся ее и не любил бывать
> дома.*



Comment: @Nikolja, Антон Палыч покинул этот мир в 1904, а его героиня живет в 1889 г. Ни о какой реформе речь ещё не шла.
То, что вы процитировали, - ирония, очень и очень по-чеховски злая, граничащая с сатирой.
Хотя согласен, ещё Ломоносов писал про ер, что это паразит, прокравшийся в русскую орфографию (это своими словами, у Ломоносова как-то ещё злее, некогда искать).
(опечатку исправил)