# Почему в приставках на  З/С фонетическое чередование  отражается на письме?

Tags: приставка

Отражение фонетического чередования звуков в приставках на З/С было утверждено в 1918 году. А с чем это связано и чья эта идея?

Большое спасибо за информационный материал.
 ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ВОПРОС: Чем не угодили именно приставки на З/С? Остальные же приставки оставили в рамках фонематического письма. Кто именно был автором идеи по поводу приставок: члены дореволюционной Орфографической комиссии  или большевики? И интересно, как современным школьникам объясняют исключение? Неужели не находится таких, кто спрашивает об этом?

Comment: Ни разу никто не спросил, просто знают, что приставки на согласный - неизменяемые (с, под, над,в,на и т.д.),пот, нат,з 
не имели бы смысла, а вот раз и рас - исключения, введённые в 1918 году, чтобы приблизить к произношению.А кто внёс идею - какая разница?
Рекомендации представлены в документе под названием «Постановления совещания при Академии наук под председательством академика А. А. Шахматова по вопросу об упрощении русского правописания, принятые 11 мая 1917 г.».

Answer (score 4):

Связано, видимо, с идеей упростить язык. Всё-таки государство рабочих и крестьян, для них сложно было понять многое в орфографии, язык учить трудно.
Вот и провели реформу, ускорили процесс, который уже шёл, реформа готовилась давно, но собирались упростить азбуку, а большевики приблизили ещё и написание к произношению.Опубликован декрет, подписанный  Луначарским, предписывающий «всем правительственным и государственным изданиям» с 1 января 1918 года «печататься согласно новому правописанию». В соответствии с реформой, из алфавита были исключены буквы Ѣ (ять), Ѳ (фита), І («и десятеричное») (заменены на Е, Ф, И); исключался твёрдый знак (Ъ) на конце слов; изменялось правило написания приставок на з/с; окончания -аго, -яго заменялось на -ого, -его; и др.

Ввели ещё одно чередование, только не  историческое, а современное. Это фонетический процесс ассимиляции по звонкости-глухости: просто здесь реализовано фонетическое, а не фонематическое написание.(Основной принцип р. буквенно-звукового письма — фонематический, при котором фонемы изображаются в соответствии с правилами алфавита -русское "трава", "травы"). При фонетическом буква соответствует реально произносимому звуку, как теперь и стало в написании русских приставок раз-/рас- .

Comment: комментарии - в моем ответе

Answer (score 2):

@Людмила,

> Опубликован декрет, подписанный Луначарским,

Это о каком декрете речь?  Его нет в сети.

Вот, кажется, единственный декрет, подписанный Луначарским в 1917 г. 
http://www.hist.msu.ru/ER/Etext/DEKRET/kompros.htm

Основного "орфографического" декрета (от 10.10.1918) Луначарский не подписывал. 
http://stcreserv.narod.ru/Tutorial/decret18.html

//--------------

По сути.

Идеи реформы были заложены Императорской Орфографической Комиссией (Фортунатов - председатель, Шахматов, Бодуэн де Куртенэ и многие другие выдающиеся русские лингвисты) в 1904-1912 г. 
http://www.gramota.ru/biblio/magazines/gramota/orthografia/28_15
Считается, что внедрению помешала Первая Мировая.
Одним из декретов первого Временного Правительства (кн. Львова, Министр народного просвещения - Мануйлов) разрешалось использование учащимися элементов новой орфографии и декларировался "постепенный" всеобщий переход на неё.
Большевики только придали глобальный и обязательный характер тому, что не ими начато.
Подробнее тут:
[Отмена старой грамматики](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8465)

По сути же вопроса - согласен.

//--------------------------------------------------
Мне указали на источник, содержащий некое изложение предложений Академической Орфографической комиссии 1904-1912 гг.
Выражаю благодарность ***mirage*** с "Грамоты"
http://orthowiki.kalan.cc/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_1918_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Из источника недвусмысленно следует, что рассматриваемые предложения по написанию приставок были сделаны ещё той, самой первой, Орфографической Комиссией. 
К сожалению, "мотивировочная часть" осталась за скобками.

Если кто её обнаружит, равно как и сам текст документов Временного Правительства,  прошу поделиться. Они мне нужны для решения еще одного вопроса, помимо тут разбираемого.

Comment: Буквоедством занимаетесь, господин хороший, но я не ошиблась и ничего не исказила :  http://gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_5_orfo1917 Новая орфография была введена двумя декретами: после первого декрета, подписанного наркомом просвещения А. В. Луначарским и опубликованного 23 декабря 1917 года (5 января 1918 года), последовал второй декрет от 10 октября 1918 года за подписью заместителя наркома М. Н. Покровского и управляющего делами Совета Народных Комиссаров В. Д. Бонч-Бруевича.

Comment: Так что не следует быть таким категоричным, кого-то обвиняя в незнании, всё это я знаю не хуже Вас и написала в ответе "реформа готовилась давно".Так что я исказила? Вам тоже  известно далеко не всё.

Comment: >кого-то обвиняя в незнании  
  
Что, простите? 

>Так что я исказила? 

Понятия не имею.  

>Вам тоже известно далеко не всё.
  
Разумеется.

Еще вопросы?  

ЗЫ За указание на дату декрета - спасибо.