# Как бы вы реформировали русский язык?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Скоро будет сто лет, как прошла крупная реформа русского языка. Исчезли некоторые буквы, пропал твердый знак с конца слов, произошли и другие упрощения.

Давайте представим, что в 2017 года будет создана комиссия по очередной реформе языка. И ваше слово там будет имеет большой вес. Вы бы поменяли что-то в нынешних правилах русского языка? Упростили бы, оптимизировали или наоборот вернули бы что-то назад? Если да, то что именно?

Answer (score 2):

1) По содержанию современная орфография в реформах не нуждается, здесь может требоваться мелкий косметический ремонт: рассмотрение обоснованности лопатинских поправок, согласование текстов Розенталя и Лопатина, наведение порядка в написании новых слов и т.д.

2) Но оформление правил должно быть принципиально иным. Текст должен содержать теоретическую часть (основные принципы орфографии и пунктуации), правила должны излагаться по системе от общего к частному и иметь объяснение (как пишется и почему так пишется), всякие исключения, примечания должны составлять второй план, а не излагаться вперемешку с основным материалом. Иными словами, **русское правописание должно приобрести вид строго логичной системы**, тогда не будет желания ее постоянно реформировать.

3) Интересно, что пунктуация в Правилах 1956 года дается по знакам, а не по темам, как сейчас. Думаю, что в этом есть определенный смысл, еще не понятый современниками.

Comment: >> русское правописание должно приобрести вид строго логичной системы, тогда не будет желания ее постоянно реформировать.                     Вообще-то у грамотных людей и сейчас не возникает желания "постоянно реформировать".

Comment: Вы за всех грамотных людей в ответе? А что  вы скажете о несостоявшихся проектах  реформы 1964 и 2000 годов?

Comment: В 1964 это, если не ошибаюсь, "заец" (не с подачи ли Никиты Сергеича?), а в 2000 – "огурци"? Это несерьёзно. Но, так или иначе, "строго логичная система" все равно невозможна. В том смысле, что она никогда не будет устраивать всех. А зуд реформаторства – он вполне объясним, недовольные всегда есть, нужно только, чтобы он не зашкаливал, находился в разумных рамках.

Comment: Только не Вам это решать. Вот спросят у вас: Вы, уважаемый Niemand, почему  пишете огурцы, заяц, как это можно объяснить? А вы в ответ - не знаю, так привык. А тогда будьте любезны писать "огурци и заец". Заглянете в словарь - а "огурци и заец" уже там обозначены. Извольте выполнять, если считаете себя грамотным.

Comment: Неужели вы не можете объяснить?! Даже от вас не ожидал. )))

Comment: Дело не в конкретных словах, а в принципе. Если правило никак не объясняется, то его всегда можно изменить, а у нас мало что объясняется. Люди, ратующие за реформы, могут руководствоваться разными соображениями, в том числе экономическими, а не только целесообразностью,  и мнение грамотных людей их вряд ли сильно интересует.

Comment: Объяснения всегда можно объявить недостаточными, или не соответствующими действительности, или... да мало ли. Не устраивают, и всё! Потому что строго математических доказательств здесь быть не может. А так-то все правила имеют свои объяснения.

Comment: Прямо-таки все? Ну, например, почему  мы пишем окончание Е, а не О  в слове  "дЕревце" после твердого Ц ? может быть, отменить правило О/Е после шипящих и Ц.? Будем писать в свежом  (каком?) молоке.

Comment: Я же не сказал, что __я__ могу всё объяснить. Но тут, подозреваю, школьная программа: лицо – полотенце, дЕревце – деревцО.. А вообще-то говоря, людям грамотным реформы невыгодны. Это в какой-то степени и на какой-то период времени "уравняет" их с не шибко грамотными, а на чёрта это надо...

Answer (score 1):

Отказавшись от одиозной приставки и соответствующего правила, узаконенных той реформой, вернул бы единую для всех случаев — **без**.

Answer (score 1):

Орфографическая реформа не является реформой языка. 
Это крайне некорректное высказывание. 
А что касается самой орфографической реформы, то она давно обсуждалась здесь - и неоднократно.

Смотрите, например
[Отмена старой грамматики](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8465)

И вообще, Вы видимо не в курсе, что в 2000-м и последующие годы работала Орфографическая комиссия под руководством В.В. Лопатина. Никаких возвратов к старой орфографии она не предполагала. Наоборот, были предложены некоторые уточнения действующего свода правил.

Так что никакого возврата к старому быть не может.

Comment: Орфография - часть языка. В вашем ответе нет ответа на заданный мной вопрос. Отвечайте по теме. "Никаких возвратов к старой орфографии она не предполагала." - Какое это имеет отношение к вопросу, если мне интересны личные мнения людей. Учитесь понимать написанный текст и заданный вопрос. У вас получится, я уверен. :--)

Comment: Спасибо за мнение.

Answer (score 0):

"русское правописание должно приобрести вид строго логичной системы"

Внутри орфографии вид строгой логичной системы утратил алфавит. Изначально логика прослеживалась, её можно восстановить, и теперь, когда реформаторы не угрожают составу алфавита, с уверенностью, что так и будет впредь, необходимо «навести порядок в доме».

Comment: И очень красивая. Такая же логика в графемах, как и в цифровых арабских.

Comment: А какая логика в том, что слово "лес" писалось через "ять"? Зачем были нужны букв "и" и "i" и т.д.?

Comment: Если не помешаю разговору, то замечу, что говорю о порядке знаков, сохраняющем логику, применённую создателями алфавита, а не о трудностях орфографии при сорока трёх буквах. Не затрудняло, не писал. Читать не затруднительно. Возвышающиеся над строкой буквы весьма способствуют.

Comment: Знаете, не очень понятно. Дайте. пожалуйста, определение: порядок знаков, сохраняющий логику,  - это... Буквально в двух словах.

Comment: Становление начертания знаков латиницы, а позже и кириллицы шло по единой логике (нашего арабского) цифрового ряда. Цифры имеют последовательность и буквенный алфавит имеет. Вернее, должен иметь. Перестановка предполагается минимальная.

Comment: Да простит меня модератор: http://e-notabene.ru/hr/article_8117.html

Comment: И какой вывод вы сделали?

Comment: По отношению к проблеме? Надо доводить до ума.